# What means this code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, c

I cant understand .type and .func in this code.

```
static struct packet_type ip_packet_type __read_mostly = {
.type = cpu_to_be16(ETH_P_IP),
.func = ip_rcv,};
```

This is referenced  in:

*net/ipv4/af_inet.c* [line 1751](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L1749)

Answer (score 2):

This is associating the IP protocol handler (`ip_rcv`) to the Ethernet IP type (`ETH_P_IP` == `0x0800`).

It is used by the `init_inet` function just below that code where it calls the [`dev_add_pack()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L1863) to add `ip_rcv` as the handler for Ethernet IP packets.

Comment: eh. Question is clearly off topic. We shouldn't encourage them by answering :(

Comment: @JourneymanGeek `:-)` it is very tempting. But, I do agree with you. Should this be moved elsewhere?

Comment: @nik I want to change ip_rcv before compile my linux but I can not .linux can not compile it.

Comment: I'm not convinced its a good fit for SO - there's a definite lack of research, for example.

Comment: be kind @JourneymanGeek and take it easy. :-)

Comment: Be a dear and take a look at the help pages...